# Solve the equation $x^{3}-3 x=\sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

> Solve the equation $x^{3}-3 x=\sqrt{x+2}$

In the solution of this author wrote -

Let $-2 \leq x \leq 2 .$ Now Setting $x=2 \cos a, 0 \leq a \leq \pi$....

But here i did not understand the reason behind taking $ 0 \leq a \leq \pi$,i mean if we can take $a$ to be any real number since domain of $\cos x$ is real numbers then why we are restricting to
$ 0 \leq a \leq \pi$ ?

Comment: Because $\cos a$ takes the entire set of values $[-1,1]$ when $0\le a\le\pi$.

Comment: why downvote ?.

Comment: People that downvote do not understand the question. In such cases i would really impose a rating condition...

Comment: @dan_fulea  That's an absurd hypothesis, and wrong in this case.

Comment: To avoid finding the same root multiple times due to periodicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for

$$0 \leq a \leq \pi \implies -1\le \cos a \le 1 \implies -2\le 2\cos a \le 2$$

which suffices to cover by a bijection the whole range for $x=2\cos a$.

Note that the assumption is due to these facts

- $\sqrt{x+2}$ requires $x\ge -2$
- for $x>2 \implies x^{3}-3 x>\sqrt{x+2}$

Comment: So if the equation is $x^3-2196749\dots =\sqrt{x+2}$, how we exclude the value $3346\dots$ from being a solution?

Comment: @dan_fulea I'm not discussing the full solution but only the assumption for the range of $a$ given the range for $x$.

Comment: And where is the problem with $x=10$ when we write $\sqrt{x+2}$?

Comment: @dan_fulea I add something also about that point.

Comment: @dan_fulea note that trying $x=10$ where we have $x^3-3x=\sqrt{x+2}$ gives $970=\sqrt{12}$, so it is not a solution.  It would also suffice in the author's text to note that once $x>2$ then $x^3-3x>\sqrt{x+2}$ which I would guess has already been done and in any case is not relevant given the OPs question.

Comment: And where did the answer use the LHS of the given equation, or anything from it. We all understand how to parametrize the interval $[-2,2]$ using the $\cos$, but just reread the question.

Comment: well, people accept already $x^3-3x>\sqrt{x+2}$ for $x>2$... so i will quit here

Comment: @dan_fulea $x^3-3x>x>\sqrt{x+2}$ for $x>2$

Answer (score 1):

They've chosen the **principal value branch** of $\arccos$.

$-2\le 2\cos a \le 2 \Rightarrow -1 \le \cos a\le 1 \Rightarrow \pi\ge a \ge 0$ or $0\le a\le\pi$

Answer (score 1):

It would be good as a first step to have an estimation for the solutions, else, without knowing that any potential real solution ($\ge -2$) lives in the interval $[-2,2]$, the argument is only partial. The question is of course valid.

Now, one possibility to work is to start with the given equation, and go in one direction to see what follows from it. We obtain:

$$(x^3-3x)^2-(x+2)=0\ .$$
Just as a digression, one can factorize the above as:
$$
(x-2)(x^2+x-1)(x^3 +x^2-2x-1)\ .
$$
For the first two factors we have "easy solutions". But there are some problems with the third factor. Digression finished, this will not be used, but it may be maybe compared finally with the obtained solutions.

At any rate, there are **at most six solutions** of the given polynomial equation of degree six.

---

Now we abandon this path, and try to get as many solutions as possible in the interval $[-2,2]$, this was the hint for question maybe.

(If we already find six solutions, we are done!)

So we are modest and search first only for such solutions. The substitution $x=2\cos 2t$ for some "angle" $t$ delivers immediately:
$$
(\dagger)
\qquad
2\cos 6t = 2|\cos t|\  .
$$
And from the weaker equation $\cos 6t \pm \cos t=0$ we collect six solutions for $(  \dagger)$ for $t$, which are
$$
0\ ,\ 
\frac {2\pi}7\ ,\ 
\frac {2\pi}5\ ,\ 
\frac {4\pi}7\ ,\ 
\frac {4\pi}5\ ,\ 
\frac {6\pi}7\ .
$$

---

The above discussion leads to my answer for the OP: We just do that substitution, thus searching only for solutions in $[-2,2]$. We expect - without any restriction - maximally six solution. *A posteriori*, after the trigonometric substitution, we have indeed six solutions. "So we had luck" and "the substitution works".

---

Final note: In fact, if we have the above list, we can check individually that each value in the list is a solution. And with the same argument, maximally six solutions, the problem is solved with minimal typing effort.

Comment: the third factor, a cubic, is listed in Reuschle, and has indeed three real roots of the form $2 \cos \frac{2k\pi}{7}.$ It is on manuscript page 6. I'm not sure what happened to the online scanned version (from Stanford) pages 5 and 6 seem missing. I have a paperback reprint at home.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer by Dan Fulea, there is a cubic factor  as "Just as a digression," namely $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1.$  This is well known, the roots are real numbers
$$ 2 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{7} \right) \; \; , \; \;
2 \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{7} \right) \; \; , \; \;
2 \cos \left( \frac{8 \pi}{7} \right) \; \; . \; \; $$

This is verified easily enough, using nothing worse than the formula for $\cos 3 \theta. $

In the original problem $x^3 - 3 x = \sqrt{x+2},$ just one of the three works, namely $ x =2 \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{7} \right) \approx -0.445$

Note that the given roots are all strictly between $-2$ and $2.$

This page from [Reuschle(1875)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP1&dq=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen) is missing from the scanned version online, I don't know what happened:

[image]

[image]